# multiple option selected based on fetch value from database using php in_array

Tags: php

I have php variable like this `$SubTopicid = $L_array["subtopicid"];`

then in option tag like this way

`<option <?php if (In_array($URow[0],explode(" ",$SubTopicid))) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="<?php echo $URow[0];?>"><?php echo $URow[1];?></option>`

issue is that multiple value is not selected

when i explode this variable `$SubTopicids = explode(" ",$SubTopicid);`

get the result of this way

```
Array ( [0] => 248 ) Array ( [0] => 72 ) Array ( [0] => 72,248 )
```

single value like **248** is selected but double value like **72,248** is not selected in option

Comment: Why do you explode `$subtopicid` with " " and not with ","? 
Are `Array ( [0] => 248 ) Array ( [0] => 72 ) Array ( [0] => 72,248 )` are 3 example of the explode or its the output of one execute?

Comment: because before explde the variable when I echo this varibale $SubTopicid = $L_array["subtopicid"]; then result show like this way 248 72 248,72

Comment: What is the `$URow[0]` look like in multi-option? Or it has to be one number value?

Comment: $RowRes=mysql_query("Select id, name from tbl_sub_topic where module_id=".$mid);
                            while($URow=mysql_fetch_array($RowRes)){}

Comment: this option tag is written in this while loop so id of sub_topic is generte in this way $URow[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to check as marked all the option from `$SubTopicid`.

If your `$SubTopicid` can include both single option and multi you may want to explode them before your `while` loop.

Consider the following:

```
$SubTopicid = "248 72 72,248";
$SubTopicids = array();
foreach(explode(" ",$SubTopicid ) as $elem)
    $SubTopicids = array_merge($SubTopicids ,explode(",",$elem));
```

In that case you array will look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 248
    [1] => 72
    [2] => 72
    [3] => 248
)
```

You can use [array-unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) if needed.

Now, when you run:

```
while($URow=mysql_fetch_array($RowRes)){
    <option <?php if (In_array($URow[0],$SubTopicids)) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="<?php echo $URow[0];?>"><?php echo $URow[1];?></option>
}
```

You will mark as selected all the given option.

Comment: Thank u so much.. now its working thanks once again for helping me